# Only a portion of the code is executed and no error message is displayed

Tags: matlab, gaussian, psychtoolbox

I am using MATLAB 2020 Psychtoolbox on Mac OS and everytime I run this code, they screen turns grey followed by an error sound, however, no error message is displayed in the command window. How do I make all the code execute?

```
% Clear the workspace
close all;
clearvars;
sca;

% Setup PTB with some default values
PsychDefaultSetup(2);

% Seed the random number generator. Here we use the an older way to be
% compatible with older systems. Newer syntax would be rng('shuffle'). Look
% at the help function of rand "help rand" for more information
rand('seed', sum(100 * clock));

  % Set the screen number to the external secondary monitor if there is one
% connected
screenNumber = max(Screen('Screens'));

% Define white, grey and black
white = WhiteIndex(screenNumber);
grey = white / 2;
black = BlackIndex(screenNumber);

% Open an on screen window
[window, windowRect] = PsychImaging('OpenWindow', screenNumber, grey);

% Get the size of the on screen window
[screenXpixels, screenYpixels] = Screen('WindowSize', window);

% Query the frame duration
ifi = Screen('GetFlipInterval', window);

% Set up alpha-blending for smooth (anti-aliased) lines
Screen('BlendFunction', window, 'GL_SRC_ALPHA', 'GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA');

% Setup the text type for the window
Screen('TextFont', window, 'Ariel');
Screen('TextSize', window, 36);

% Get the centre coordinate of the window
[xCenter, yCenter] = RectCenter(windowRect);


%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%                       Keyboard information
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

% Define the keyboard keys that are listened for. We will be using the left
% and right arrow keys as response keys for the task and the escape key as
% a exit/reset key
escapeKey = KbName('ESCAPE');
leftKey = KbName('LeftArrow');
rightKey = KbName('RightArrow');
downKey = KbName('DownArrow');

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%                       Fixation cross
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

% Here we set the size of the arms of our fixation cross
fixCrossDimPix = 10;

% Now we set the coordinates (these are all relative to zero we will let
% the drawing routine center the cross in the center of our monitor for us)
xCoords = [-fixCrossDimPix fixCrossDimPix 0 0];
yCoords = [0 0 -fixCrossDimPix fixCrossDimPix];
allCoords = [xCoords; yCoords];

% Set the line width for our fixation cross
lineWidthPix = 4;

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%                            Colors
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

% We are going to use three colors for this demo. Red, Green and blue.
wordList = {'Green', 'Magenta', 'Orange'};
Colors = [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0.8500 0.3250 0.0980];

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%                  Define positions of sequences
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

leftX = screenXpixels/2.5;
leftY = screenXpixels/1.6;
rightX = screenXpixels/1.7;
rightY = screenYpixels/1.6;
upX = screenXpixels/2.1;
upY = screenYpixels/2.6;

left = [leftX leftY];
right = [rightX rightY];
up = [upX upY];

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%                  Randomise temporal order of trials
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
 
trialorder = [1 0 0 0 0];
randtemp = shuffle(trialorder);

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%                           Trial loop
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
nTrials = 5;

for trial = 1:randtemp
    
    % randomise position of sequences
    randpos = shuffle(left, right, up);
    
    % fixation cross
    % Draw the fixation cross in white, set it to the center of our screen and
    % set good quality antialiasing
    Screen('DrawLines', window, allCoords,...
    lineWidthPix, white, [xCenter yCenter], 2);

    % Derive distributions
    seq1 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5); % high variance
    seq2 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5); % low variance
    seq3 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5); % low variance
    
    seq4 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    seq5 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    seq6 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    
    seq7 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    seq8 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    seq9 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    
    seq10 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    seq11 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    seq12 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    
    seq13 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    seq14 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);
    seq15 = distribution(0.02, 0.126, 0.146, 0.106, 5);

    if trial == 1 
       DrawFormattedText(window, 'Name the color \n\n Press Any Key To Begin',...
       'center', 'center', black);
       Screen('Flip', window);
       KbStrokeWait;
    end
    
    if randtemp() == 0
        % trail 1
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq1), white, randpos(1));
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq2), white, randpos(2));
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq3), white, randpos(3));
        WaitSecs(0.75)
        Screen('Flip', window);
        KbStrokeWait;
           
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq2), white, randpos(1));
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq3), white, randpos(2));
        WaitSecs(0.75)
        Screen('Flip', window);
        KbStrokeWait;
        
        %trial 2
        %repeat
        
    else 
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq13), white, randpos(1));
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq14), white, randpos(2));
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq15), white, randpos(3));
        WaitSecs(0.75)
        Screen('Flip', window);
        KbStrokeWait;
           
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq13), white, randpos(1));
        Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq14), white, randpos(2));
        WaitSecs(0.75)
        Screen('Flip', window);
        KbStrokeWait;
    end
end       

        

      

% Flip to the screen
Screen('Flip', window);

% Wait for a key press
KbStrokeWait;

% Clear the screen
sca
```

The 'distribution' function is a self-made function that generates a Gaussian distribution of random numbers with a specified mean, variance, upper limit, lower limit and a given amount of numbers:

```
function distribution(va, mu, ul, ll, nvals)
 multiplier=10;
 x = mu + randi(multiplier*nvals,1)*sqrt(va); % Generate sufficient random numbers
 idx = (ll <= x) & (x <= ul); % Extract the value in the given range [min max]
 while sum(idx)<nvals
    multiplier=multiplier+1;
    x = mu + randi(multiplier*nvals,1)*sqrt(va); % Generate sufficient random numbers
    idx = (ll <= x) & (x <= ul); % Extract the value in the given range [min max]
 end
 x = x(idx);
 x = x(1:nvals); % Extract numbers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only seeing the grey screen because the error doesn't cause the Psychtoolbox window (which you have set to have a grey background) to close. To have the screen close and display the error, wrap your code in a try, catch statement, which will close the screen and rethrow an error, if encountered.

For example (here the word CODE is just a placeholder, instead replace it with your actual code)

```
try
    CODE
catch e
    sca;
    rethrow(e)
end
```

In this case, if an error is encountered within the body of the try statement, it will go to the catch statement, calling the error `e`. First the screen will be closed with `sca`, then the error will be actually shown, via `rethrow`.

In terms of the actual error you were encountering, I think there are at least few issues with your current code:

1. The Shuffle function in Psychtoolbox is capitalized - 'Shuffle' and
   has a single input. Here, you're using 'shuffle', and providing
   three separate inputs.

   Instead of providing 'left', 'right' and 'up' as separate inputs,
   combined them into a elements of a single cell array:

   replacing: `randpos = shuffle(left, right, up);`

   with: `randpos = Shuffle({left, right, up});`

   and select them as elements of a cell array:

   replacing: `Screen('DrawText', num2str(seq1), white, randpos(1));`

   with: `Screen('DrawText', window, num2str(seq1), white, [], black, randpos{1}(1), randpos{1}(2));`
2. In the distribution function you have defined, you haven't included an output argument. Replace your current first function line with: `function x = distribution(va, mu, ul, ll, nvals)`
3. `KbStrokeWait` without an input parameter only checks the first keyboard attached. This may be ignoring keypresses if you are using an external keyboard on a laptop, for example. Using `KbStrokeWait(-3)` will check all attached devices.
4. Your distribution function seems to either not be converging on a solution, or taking a long time to identify a solution, since it seems to be randomly generating values and then checking that is has enough in your desired interval. I would instead start with the built function to generate random normal values. For example the following will generate 5 values from a distribution with a mean of 0.02 and a variance of 0.126. It doesn't implement checking that all the generated values are within a given range, though: `randn(1, 5) * sqrt(0.126) + 0.02;`
5. You're missing the window pointer in the call to DrawText.

There may be other issues as well, but addressing these will get you started.

Comment: Hi, I replaced the code as you suggested for randomizing the position of the stimuli, but I'm not sure how to reference the individual x and y co-ordinates in the 'left', 'right' and 'up' vectors within the randpos array. The following error occurs when I use the code you suggested: `Error using Screen
Usage:

[newX,newY,textHeight]=Screen('DrawText', windowPtr, text [,x] [,y] [,color] [,backgroundColor] [,yPositionIsBaseline] [,swapTextDirection]);

Error in Third_draft (line 218)
    Screen('DrawText', window, num2str(seq1), randpos{1}, randpos{1}, [0 1 0]);` Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my answer. Since you are storing X and Y in a single array, but the Screen function needs them as separate variables, you have to index into the randpos array twice, once for X and once for Y:

Screen('DrawText', window, num2str(seq1), white, [], black, randpos{1}(1), randpos{1}(2));